# vertical padding for input elements in webkit browsers has no effect

Tags: css, forms, input, webkit, padding

I am unable to set a vertical/top padding for the text/placeholder in input elements.

The following code will work in IE/Firefox/Opera, but not in Safari/Chrome:

CSS:

```
input
{
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 100px;
 padding: 70px 25px 10px 25px;
 width: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter text here"/>
```

The webkit Developer Tools display the metrics as they should be, but the text is still in the middle of the input.

Something similar might be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355742/vertical-alignment-for-form-input-fields-in-safari-and-chrome) (unanswered though).

Comment: This is a webkit bug and they don't plan on fixing it: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32981

Answer (score 0):

Just tested that and its bizzare how Chrome behaves. Could you maybe stick the input in a div and use padding on that?

Answer (score 0):

inputs are inline elements. Inline elements don't accept vertical padding.

add: `display:block` to your CSS, you will then have to add `float:left` and clear your floats afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way to set vertical padding in Webkit.

Use the `height` property, to add vertical padding. You may need to use `line-height` or `padding-top`/`padding-bottom` to vertically center the text across browsers.