# How can I control the height of text inputs and submit input buttons in different browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have a very little but hard (for me) problem to solve.

I have a text input, and a submit button. I need them to be the exact same height and for this to be true across Chrome and Firefox, ideally internet explorer also.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="email" /><input type="submit" value="»" />
```

CSS

```css
input[type=text] {
    width: 218px;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

input[type=submit], input[type=text] {
    padding: 9px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    float: left;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I've setup this basic code on a **[jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/e6aTd/)**

You should notice if you load it in chrome, the button is less height than the text input and in firefox, its larger.

What am I missing?

Comment: Tips : dont use shorthand property `background` when you r only applying  single property( `background-color` here)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Remove/add `line-height: 18px;` for both.

Comment: this created consistent height for the text inputs, yet the button still remained a different height in firefox.

Answer (score 9):

Vertical padding of the submit button has no effect. This [seems to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670498/vertical-padding-for-input-elements-in-webkit-browsers-has-no-effect) a [webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32981). You can solve the problem by specifying explit heights and increasing the height of the submit button by the top and bottom padding of the input field.

```
input[type=text] {height: 60px;}
input[type=submit] {height: 78px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your padding that is applying wrong to your button.
Trying solving it like this.

```
input[type=submit], input[type=text] {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  float: left;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px; /* or whatever height necessary */
}
```

Additionally, you can keep the padding left and right on your button like this.

```
input[type=submit] {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input {
 height: 19px;
 }
```

This maybe?
Also, remove the padding property.
http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/e6aTd/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the padding that is making problems. Try removing the padding, setting the button to a fixed height and make the offset with line-height.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the height and work on the actual height of the input text field just by padding/font-size

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uu64P/)

Answer (score 0):

Removing/adding `line-height: 18px;` for both is not a perfect solution because I see a little difference height in firefox...

The best solution I found is to put a div arround and set its style to `display: flex`.

All is perfect this way.

```
    body {
        background: #ccc;
    }
    div{
        display: flex;
    }
    input[type=text] {
      width: 218px;
    }
    input[type=submit] {
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
    }
    input[type=submit], input[type=text] {
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 25px;
      border: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    <div><input type="text" name="email"  /><input type="submit" value="»" /></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

TRY

```
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 218px;
}
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/e6aTd/1/)