# Why Internet Explorer renders inputs differently?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Can anyone explain me, why `<input>` and `<a>` have different heights (while having same font, padding, margin and border settings) in Internet Explorer 9-11? Firefox and Chrome render them with the same height.

Here is example:

HTML

```
<input class="text" value="input"/>
<a class="text">button</a>
```

CSS

```
.text {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

And [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashustariov/88f3n/3/)

Is there any way to prevent such behavior in IE? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Question similar to this one which already got many answers and 18000 views.
I think you will find a solution to yours there too

[CSS - Exact same height and alignment of button and input text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726135/css-exact-same-height-and-alignment-of-button-and-input-text-box)

Also you could just try to give both of them a height: XYpx so you can make sure they will always have the same heights. I guess giving them a height will also be better for your styling later on

I also found this Question on how to control the heights in different browsers

[How can I control the height of text inputs and submit input buttons in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184210/how-can-i-control-the-height-of-text-inputs-and-submit-buttons-in-different-brow)

Comment: The problem is, that provided example illustrates the main reason of issue I'm currently experiencing. Those elements are under different nodes, so I cannot just wrap them in common element and I cannot set their height, since font is dynamic and may change.

Comment: the main problem why those boxes are not on the same height is the vertical text align which you change with the `line-height: 1.4em;` without this they are both set to the same height. The "input" text got a vertical align center while the "button" text got a different one. so when you use the line-height the "input" will change the height from the middle while "button" wont

Comment: See here http://jsfiddle.net/n64gd/1/ with height
or here http://jsfiddle.net/n64gd/4/ without height

Comment: Thank you - line-height solved the issue!