# Why is a input box of type="submit" shorter than its given height?

Tags: html, css

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z7Lkee07/2/):

```css
#hours {
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
}
#button {
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<label class="hours">
  <input value="0" min="0" id="hours" />
</label>
<label>
  <input type="submit" value="Set Alarm" id="button" />
</label>
```

I have two input tags. One of it is of `type="submit"`. Both the elements are given a `height:80px` but the submit button appears shorter than the text box.

Why is it so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184210/how-can-i-control-the-height-of-text-inputs-and-submit-buttons-in-different-brow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because submit button has `box-sizing: border-box` to default. So in your case `80px height - 1px padding top - 1px padding bottom - 2px border top - 2px border bottom = 74px height`. You can inspect your elements by pressing F12 or the right button of the mouse over the submit button and the clicking inspect element on Chrome. After that go to Computed and you will see the exact dimensions for *paddings, margins, borders, width and height*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

That i think is because of the border,you can remove it by using `box-sizing:border-box`

```css
#hours {
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#button {
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
    line-height:0;
}
```

```html
<label class="hours">
    <input type="number" value="0" min="0" id="hours" />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="submit" value="Set Alarm" id="button" />
</label>
```

Comment: Glad i could help @uʍopǝpısdn

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this css rule to your button:

```
box-sizing: content-box;
```

Try it in the snippet below:

```css
#hours{
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
}
#button {
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<label class="hours">
    <input value="0" min="0" id="hours" />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="submit" value="Set Alarm" id="button" />
</label>
```

More about box-sizing read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 0):

```
        <label class="hours">
      <input value="0" min="0" id="hours" />
   </label>
      <label>
       <input type="submit" value="Set Alarm" id="button" />
           </label>

   <style>
     #hours {
           width: 120px;
           height: 80px;
           border: 1px solid;
            }
     #button{
           width: 120px;
           height: 80px;
           border: 0px none;
           margin-left: -5px;
            }
   </style>
```

Comment: Please provide some sort of explanation about what is going on in your snippet.

Comment: check height variance  is equal because i make border 0